# What does qlen 1000 mean for a noqueue qdisc

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, network-interface, ip

`ip addr show` output from within a Kubernetes pod

```
root@customer-fd99fb7dc-82hrr:/app# ip -c addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0@if6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8e:e3:d2:b5:d2:94 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.171.139/32 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8ce3:d2ff:feb5:d294/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`etho0@1f6` is one end of the `veth` pair. This explains `qdisc noqueue`

My understanding of noqueue qdisc is that, it sends the network packet immediately (if it can) or would drop it otherwise. So, I assumed that noqueue is not backed by any queues. But, `qlen 1000` is contradicting with my understanding.

Does it mean `noqueue` has an internal queue? Can I think of noqueue qdisc as pfifo_fast minus the 3 internal classes/bands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qlen` is the interface parameter set with `ip link set eth0 txqueuelen 1000` or `ifconfig eth0 txqueuelen 1000` ([see ifconfig(8)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ifconfig.8.html))

In the kernel it is called `dev->tx_queue_len` and defaults to `DEFAULT_TX_QUEUE_LEN = 1000`. This is what `ip link ls` shows.

When a queueing discipline is attached to a device it takes the the device `qlen` setting and uses that.  When you replace the qdisc with another, it still uses the same `qlen`.  Or ignores it, as `noqueue` qdisc does.

(disclaimer: not a kernel expert)